# Qual é o jeito mais veloz?

Tags: java, mysql, banco-de-dados, desempenho, arraylist

Eu fiz um joguinho em Java e os dados dos jogadores estão no banco de dados, quando um jogador entra, ele é colocado numa `ArrayList<PlayerData>` onde contém os *getters* and *setters* de *level*, *dinheiro* e etc.

Quando o jogador sai do jogo, os dados são salvos no banco de dados e a cada 60 segundos todos os dados dos jogadores dentro do jogo também são salvos.

Eu modifico o *level*, dinheiro na `ArrayList<PlayerData>` em vez de modificar direto no banco de dados (dentro do Java).

O "jogo" ficaria mais rápido se em vez de eu mudar pela `ArrayList<PlayerData>` e depois salvar no Banco de Dados, eu modificasse direto no banco? Ou seria a mesma coisa? Teria algum jeito de melhorar isto?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difícil cravar sem saber de mais informações, mas é altamente provável que manter na memória será sempre mais rápido, em condições normais. Acesso a um dispositivo externo sempre foi muito mais lento, até mesmo se for um SSD. Isto pode mudar com as memórias não voláteis, mas ainda não sabemos o quanto.

Mas se está preocupado com performance pode rever outras coisas na aplicação, quem sabe eliminando *getters* e *setters*, que em muitos cenários são desnecessários e causam lentidão. Provavelmente tem outras coisas no código que estão tornando ele lento e nem sabe.

Answer (score -1):

Creio eu que é muito mais viável modificar direto no banco e apenas recuperar as informações, do que você usar o código pra depois salvar, claro que se quiser fazer os dois pode usar uma Thread, com certeza isso melhoraria a performance do app, pois não necessitaria fazer uma de cada vez, mas as duas independentes uma da outra.